# How to order by dob, then order surname, then first name if in the same age bracket?

Tags: mysql

So far my query looks like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT (child_fname,' ',child_sname) AS 'Name', child_dob AS 'DoB',
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, child_dob)/365.25) as 'Age'
FROM Child
ORDER BY child_dob, child_sname, child_fname;
```

I have managed to order the `Age`, but don't know how to order the `child_sname`, then `child_fname` when they are the same age?

Comment: what you have is correct, the oldest first.

Comment: maybe you want child dob desc, child_sname, child_fname?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your problem is..

THis would order 1st by age, then by sname, then my fname

```
SELECT CONCAT (child_fname,' ',child_sname) AS 'Name', child_dob AS 'DoB',
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, child_dob)/365.25) as 'Age'
FROM Child
ORDER BY FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, child_dob)/365.25), child_sname, child_fname;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT (child_fname,' ',child_sname) AS 'Name', child_dob AS 'DoB',
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, child_dob)/365.25) as 'Age'
FROM Child
ORDER BY FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, child_dob)/365.25), child_sname, child_fname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort on multiple columns, and you can sort different columns in different directions asc/desc like below :

```
  SELECT 
    CONCAT (child_fname,' ',child_sname) aS Name,
    child_dob aS DoB,
    FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, child_dob)/365.25) as Age
    FROM Child
    ORDER BY Age,child_sname, child_fname;
```